# Adding nodes in private network of docker containers hosted in different VMs

Tags: private-blockchain, docker, node-discovery, bootnodes

I am trying to create a non-local private network with go-ethereum running on docker containers hosted in different Virtual Machines. I am having a hard time trying to make the nodes recognize each other. I wonder which is the best strategy to add peers now that bootnode is not working properly ([Open Issue #3703](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3703)). I have followed many aspects of the [Vertigobr project](https://github.com/vertigobr/ethereum).

Knowing that `--nodiscover` should be enabled to avoid connecting with nodes external to the private network, these are my questions:

1. Is `--nat extip:<VM_EXT_IP>` the most convenient `nat` configuration?
2. Is only one node (a main one) in possession of the `static-nodes.json` file and it automatically links itself to the nodes in the file?
3. According to "Connecting to the network" in the Ethereum's documentation `admin.addPeer("enodeURL")` only adds nodes temporarily. Does that mean that I have to keep track of my list of nodes in a database, for example, regenerate the `static-nodes.json` when a new node is created, and restart my "main" node to reload this file? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare your `nodekey` for each node in advance. It is just a 512-bit random number. Then **store them** somewhere, along with the public ECDSA keys derived from there.

The public keys are the components of the `enode` you need to establish connections using the `--bootnode` command option, as well as the `admin.addPeer()` function in console.

Forming the `enode` is as easy as getting public keys, IPs and port, for example

```
enode://844c9c9e926a96e67fae7124bf6fcb6ecf37d121e2d3031db4b7d7bdd1388d9fc33c96c70535c65fcf34d8a4258fd40a9a7e2c24ac92bb152bd0261464b845d1@192.168.1.1:9915
```

Here is a (*non-safe* as it doesn't use `/dev/random`) one-liner to get your `nodekey`

```
perl -e '@c=("a".."f",0..9);$p.=$c[rand(scalar @c)] for 1..64; print "$p\n"'
```

And Here is a quick utility in `go` using the `geth` library to get your public key

https://gist.github.com/hermanjunge/8d0998f1fb2fd87870b57c63fe1f46c8

Comment: Hi Herman, thank you for your quick reply! I guess the key file is only  for those nodes intended as bootnodes and I could have only some that are being referenced by all other nodes on the blockchain. Well I was able to run your code and I get two keys: `246592eacb950b1a61805dddbd1faa92161befa98d04de52b45f78a8b4f6c0db` and `311feee911639c757c305e07675793eb2d5cb3c6011764ad50d1e9c9b5a07ff9e6f4a594f3938552314434be45560a8a3e36850224c288fd8c8a6201103df05c`

the long one is the enode public key, right? is the short one the nodekey (ECDSA key) ?

Comment: Yes @betty, so by starting your node with the flag `--nodekeyhex  246592eacb950b1a61805dddbd1faa92161befa98d04de52b45f78a8b4f6‌ `, you ensure that you always have the same `enode` value.

Comment: Thanks :) I also managed to run the bootnode code with `go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/bootnode` and then running `go run main.go --genkey "/some/dir/bootnode.key"` where `main.go` is the main go file of the downloaded bootnode folder.