# What is the bootnode command in the go-ethereum documentation?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

In the [go-ethereum docs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#creating-the-rendezvous-point) there is reference to a `bootnode` command:

> Creating the rendezvous point
>
> With all nodes that you want to run initialized to the desired genesis
>   state, you'll need to start a bootstrap node that others can use to
>   find each other in your network and/or over the internet. The clean
>   way is to configure and run a dedicated bootnode:
>
> `$ bootnode --genkey=boot.key`
>
> `$ bootnode --nodekey=boot.key`
>
> With the bootnode online, it will display an enode URL that other
>   nodes can use to connect to it and exchange peer information. Make
>   sure to replace the displayed IP address information (most probably
>   `[::]`) with your externally accessible IP to get the actual enode URL.
>
> Note: You could also use a full fledged Geth node as a bootnode, but
>   it's the less recommended way.

Is this command part of go-ethereum or a separate program?

My computer fails to find the command.

I have tried install via `apt-get install bootnode` gives "no such package"

I'm also unsure what the `boot` object is (with `key` attribute).

Is anyone able to clarify this?

Why is it not recommended to have the bootnode be a full node?

Comment: related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12444/adding-nodes-in-private-network-of-docker-containers-hosted-in-different-vms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it had previously been a part of the "[Geth and Tools](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/)" release package, but it's gone missing... An issue was raised a couple of days ago: [#3703](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3703)

With regards to what it does, further up the page you linked to there's a description of each of the standalone tools (yes, they're separate executables):

> bootnode
>
> Stripped down version of our Ethereum client implementation
>   that only takes part in the network node discovery protocol, but does
>   not run any of the higher level application protocols. It can be used
>   as a lightweight bootstrap node to aid in finding peers in private
>   networks.

Comment: thanks, I'm guessing `genkey` is generate key pair and then `nodekey` assigns public key to enodeURL?

Comment: Almost - I think the enode is derived from the key itself, and `nodekey` is just a quick way of assigning an enode to your private node each time it starts. Have a look at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster#setup-bootnode

Answer (score 4):

**bootnode** is back in main source of go-ethereum (as of today). If you build from source, it will be available under **build** and for make you used;
`make all`

A network is initialized to a `genesis state`. All the nodes connected to same bootnode are in fact connected to the same genesis state. In other words as referred from ethereum official docs,

[Ethereum - Private Network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network)