# Downside of geth's incoming UDP port(s) being closed?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running geth in a network situation where incoming UDP ports are closed.

It seems to be working OK. Right now my geth node has 11 peers on the Goerli testnet. However I don't know how many there should be.

What is the downside of not having incoming UDP available?

Comment: See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26940/port-30304-udp-or-is-it-30301-udp.

Comment: Ismael: That answer says we need 30304 for UDP, but a comment on the answer says we only need 30303 for both TCP and UDP (except for backwards compatibility; and given that the comment was from 2017, that probably isn't important anymore). Additionally, there is no need for 30301 UDP. Could you (or someone) please confirm that that's all correct?

Comment: If I remember correctly UDP isn't used that much in Ethereum, mostly for peer discovery.