# Bootnode command not found

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority, bootnodes

Working on this [blog](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8)

Tried to initialize bootnode throws and error

Comment: Add the error that you're getting

Comment: Bootnode : command not found

Comment: How did you install geth? It seems `bootnode` binary wasn't installed

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have already got the answer but since this thread is answerless. So here is your answer.

It was a bug in ethereum ci package (check [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3703)) and you can install bootnode with following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bootnode
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the help command

```
NETWORKING OPTIONS:
  --bootnodes value     Comma separated enode URLs for P2P discovery bootstrap (set v4+v5 instead for light servers)
  --bootnodesv4 value   Comma separated enode URLs for P2P v4 discovery bootstrap (light server, full nodes)
  --bootnodesv5 value   Comma separated enode URLs for P2P v5 discovery bootstrap (light server, light nodes)
```

You should be able to run like in the example here

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#how-peers-are-found

```
geth --bootnodes enode://pubkey1@ip1:port1,enode://pubkey2@ip2:port2,enode://pubkey3@ip3:port3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the commands in sequence here:

https://github.com/kyriediculous/clique-test/blob/master/startNode.sh

The bash file won't work but you can copy paste the commands :).

edit:

```
geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json
geth --datadir node2/ init genesis.json

bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310


geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30321 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://cfb21bfd52f947041e020dfac76e51b6c466254053335b1e46107c0bbb1235e654a2fe10a2a23042437120d4233c3475d87e69db308c507c61f98bdc40d07720@127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 999 --gasprice '0' -unlock '0xbba513f6e464e9f7d0c08125621e92598b1c28d6' --password node1/password.txt --mine
geth --datadir node2/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30322 --rpc --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8502 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes 'enode://cfb21bfd52f947041e020dfac76e51b6c466254053335b1e46107c0bbb1235e654a2fe10a2a23042437120d4233c3475d87e69db308c507c61f98bdc40d07720@127.0.0.1:30310' --networkid 999 --gasprice '0' -unlock '0xaed59d65d7e4464d15999978b745f4ed9169b52a' --password node2/password.txt --mine
```

Comment: Link you share does not open.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that development tools for geth was not added during the install process, click on the install file again and select the **development tools**:

[image]

After doing this bootnode worked.

Following tutorial: https://github.com/ConsenSys-Academy/geth-poa-tutorial

Hint to solution at: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12504/56328

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads
download `Geth & Tools`, which include `bootnode`.